# Create custom calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I need to create a calendar with my own numeration. I don't even know how to approach this problem.

Here is the text of the job.

On the planet Chronos, the millennium of the founding of the colony is celebrated, today is August 24, 1001, Tuesday. The foundation day was also Tuesday.
The Chronos calendar is similar to that of the earth: 12 months of 30 days, in February of a leap year there are 31 days. A year is a leap year if its number is a multiple of 5, but of the multiples of 100, only multiples of 500 are leap years, for example, 700, 800 and 900 are common years, 1000 is a leap year.
It is necessary to write a function that finds the day of the week on Chronos for any given date.

I came up with a check for a leap year. It wasn't hard.

```
function isLeapYear (year) {
        return year%5 === 0 && (0 !== year%100 || year%500 === 0);
    }
```

But how can create a calendar, create an array for all years, i'm not sure if this path is correct.

```
let year = {};

    for (m=1;m<=12;m++){
        year[m] = {};
    }

    var x = 0;
    $.each(year, function(index, value) {
        for (d = 1; d<=30; d++){
            value[d] = ++x;
            if (x === 7){
                x = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(year);
```

Can something like this be used to create the year

I will be glad for any help.
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Are you asking how to do your homework?

Comment: It seems that yes, this does not change the fact that I can ask for help.I don't need to be decided for me, please give me an idea of how to do it

Comment: Sure! just asking... here are some hints https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-a-leap-year based on our calendar...

Comment: How to find a date in the Gregorian calendar, I understand, but I have a different case. Can't use getDate () or getMonth (). I'll probably have to create an array for all years from 0 - 1001

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this puzzle differently, we can locate the day of the week of January the first then deduct the day of the week for other dates from it.

To achieve we need a helper array for the days of week:

```
const daysOfWeek = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday'
];
```

Along with some helper functions:

```
// Helper method needed to shift arrays in a cyclic way
// We need this to rotate the array above since our reference here is a Tuesday
Array.prototype.rotate = function(count) {
  return [...this.slice(count, this.length), ...this.slice(0, count)];
};

// Your helper function :)
function isLeapYear(year) {
    return year%5 === 0 && (0 !== year%100 || year%500 === 0);
} 

// Helper function to calculate how many leap years have passed since year 0
function leapYearsUntil(year) {
    let c = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < year; i++) {
        c += isLeapYear(i);
    }
    
    return c;
}
```

Then basically the solution is to locate the day of the week for January the first in year zero, then calculate the day of the week for any date using that as a reference.

```
function getDayOfWeek(dateString) {
    const daysSinceJanTheFirst = 30*12 + 7*30 + 24;
    // 1 year (non leap year) + 7 months  + 24 days

    const dayJanTheFirst = daysOfWeek.rotate(2).reverse()[daysSinceJanTheFirst % 7];
    // We know that '24/08/0001' is a Tuesday
    // So we rotate the days of week array by 2 to start counting from Tuesday
    // The reverse is needed because we are going back in time   

    const daysOfWeekRef = daysOfWeek.rotate(daysOfWeek.indexOf(daysOfWeek) + 2);
    // Similarly, now that we know what day is the January the first
    // We just fast forward to the day we need to calculate 

    const dateArray = dateString.split('/');
    const d = parseInt(dateArray[0]);
    const m = parseInt(dateArray[1]);
    const y = parseInt(dateArray[2]);

    const days = d + 30*(m-1) + (isLeapYear(y) * m > 2) + y * 30 * 12 + leapYearsUntil(y);
    const dayOfWeek = daysOfWeekRef[days % 7];
        
    console.log(dateString, 'is a', dayOfWeek); // For debug
    
    return dayOfWeek;
}
```

The following fiddle contains the js code along with some assertions to test it:

https://jsfiddle.net/jxmbhup3/ (results are shown in the console)